# Obtaining the volume of function with double integrals in Mathematica

Tags: numerical-integration

[image: Spected integral]

I want to obtain the volume of a function with a double integral. To solve this problem y have to evaluate in respect to x +-sqrt(y-y^2) but when I try to substitute I get this error:

Error:

[image: Sqrt[y - y^2] is not a valid limit of integration]

NIntegrate[func1, {x, -Sqrt[y - y^2], Sqrt[y - y^2]}, {y, 0, 1}]

[image: Sqrt[y - y^2] is not a valid limit of integration]

NIntegrate[func2, {x, -Sqrt[y - y^2], Sqrt[y - y^2]}, {y, 0, 1}]

My code:

func1 = 1 - y^2 - x^2

func2 = 1 - y

NIntegrate[func1, {x, -Sqrt[y - y^2], Sqrt[y - y^2]}, {y, 0, 1}]

NIntegrate[func2, {x, -Sqrt[y - y^2], Sqrt[y - y^2]}, {y, 0, 1}]

NIntegrate Is the only way I find to solve a double Integral and get a numerical number, yet I can’t use those limits

Is there a way to get around this error?

Comment: Outermost limits of a multiple integral should come first in `NIntegrate[]`, per the docs. `NIntegrate[1 - x^2 - y^2, {y, 0, 1}, {x, -Sqrt[y - y^2], Sqrt[y - y^2]}]` (Compare this with the more natural specification `NIntegrate[1 - x^2 - y^2, {x, y} ∈ Disk[{0, 1/2}, 1/2]]`.)

Comment: This is not an error, but a feature. `NIntegrate` can only provide a *numerical* result if the integrand is a numerical function (it is here), and likewise are the limits of integration (they are not).

Comment: J. M., your solution also worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know why you are using `NIntegrate` since the limit for inner integral is symbolic.

```
ClearAll[y, x];
Integrate[
  Integrate[(1 - x^2 - y^2), {x, -Sqrt[y - y^2], Sqrt[y - y^2]}], {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
  N[%]
  (*0.490874*)
```

> NIntegrate Is the only way I find to solve a double Integral

Sorry, I do not understand the above. Why? `Integrate` does work.

Comment: There is no need to call `Integrate[]` twice if you follow *Mathematica*'s convention for multiple integrals: `Integrate[1 - x^2 - y^2, {y, 0, 1}, {x, -Sqrt[y - y^2], Sqrt[y - y^2]}]`

Comment: @J.M. I know that. But because I do not want to worry about the correct order, I always do it this way. By writing explicit double integrals. For me, it is more clear and I do not have to guess (I fell into the order trap before many times. There are many questions on this on this site by users confused on result they obtained that way). It is also how I would do it by hand.  So for me, it is just more clear, even thought it is not as short to write.

Comment: Learning a lot thanks